# Abstract Derived class without abstract method implementation

Tags: c#, abstract-class

Assume I have a class as:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
   internal abstract void Add(int i , int j);
}
```

a child class as:

```
public class Child : BaseClass
{

}
```

as I am inheriting *Child* class from BaseClass I should implement `Add()` method in it
but I do not want to implement Add method here is it possible? If possible how can I achieve           it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `Child` meant to be `abstract`?

Comment: why not just change the add method into virtual instead of abstract?

Comment: If you don't implement Add, Child has to be marked abstract too

Comment: @ reptildarat I want it to be abstract

Comment: That is a point of abstracts :/ Dont use abstract if you dont want to implement Add

Comment: You will have to mark the child class of abstract. If you do not want the Child class as abstract.

Comment: I smell XY: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: What would you expect to happen if someone called the `Add()` method for a child class that did not implement it (assuming such a thing was possible)?

Comment: Maybe implement, but just simple exception: `internal override void Add(int i , int j) { throw new NotSupportedException(); };`

Comment: I may want to implement Add in some other child class then ??

Comment: @  vc 74 and  tranceporter thanks for your answers

Comment: Also note that your classes are `public` but your method is `internal`. If types defined outside of the assembly are intended to be able to subclass these types they will be unable to as it will be impossible for them to provide the implementation of the internal method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to declare your Child class as abstract too, if you don't want to implement Add function in Child class.

Answer (score 5):

If you dont want to implement the method, you could do the following:

1. Mark `Child` as abstract too:

   ```
   public abstract class Child : BaseClass { }
   ```
2. Or, make the method virtual:

   ```
   public abstract class BaseClass 
   {
       internal virtual void Add(int i , int j) { }
   }
   ```
3. Or, override the method and make it virtual:

   ```
   public abstract class Child : BaseClass
   {
       // Empty method does nothing; also could be overridden.
       internal override void Add(int i , int j) { } 
   }
   ```

Comment: @user2176592 would you mind marking the question as answered?